# LIFO in javascript cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Trying to save last five search in cookies with LIFO(Last in first out) concept.
When search six query then it will replace the last one. how can we achieve this.
I tried this code but its saving only one value.

```
    function setCookie(key, value) {  
       var expires = new Date();  
       expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + 31536000000); //1 year  
       document.cookie = key + '=' + value + ';expires=' + expires.toUTCString();  
       } 

    function getCookie(key) {  
       var keyValue = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + key + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');  
       return keyValue ? keyValue[2] : null;  
       }  

    function setCookieToBrowser(){
    var searchString=$("#auto").val();
    setCookie('lastSearch', searchString);  
    }

    function getCookiefromBrowser(){
    $('#auto').val(getCookie('lastSearch'));
    }
    getCookiefromBrowser();
    $('#frmmainSearch2').submit(function() {
     setCookieToBrowser()
      return true;
    });


 <form id="frmmainSearch2" action="#" method="post">
 <input type="text" id="auto">
 <input type="submit" value="save">
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbmag0jf/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is to store an array in the cookie and shifting that array when the maximum length is reached.

This is the process step by step:

1. Try to read the list of queries from the cookie
2. If the value is present in the cookie, do `JSON.parse` to get the array. If it wasn't present, use an empty array
3. When the form is submitted, check the length of the array of previous queries. If it's already containing five queries, do `shift()` on the array to remove the first item
4. Push the current query at the end of the array.
5. Update the cookie, using `JSON.stringify` on the array.

See the updated code [in the updated JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbmag0jf/3/) or below:

```
function setCookieToBrowser(){
  var searchString=$("#auto").val();

  if(previousQueries.length === 5) previousQueries.shift();
  previousQueries.push(searchString);
  setCookie('lastSearch', JSON.stringify(previousQueries));  
}

function getCookieFromBrowser(){
  var cookieValue = getCookie('lastSearch');
  if(cookieValue !== null) {
    previousQueries = JSON.parse(cookieValue);
    console.log('previous queries', previousQueries)
    var datalist = document.querySelector('datalist');
    datalist.innerHTML = '';

    for(var i=previousQueries.length - 1; i>=0;i--) {
      var option = document.createElement('option');
      option.value = previousQueries[i];
      datalist.appendChild(option);
    }
    $('#auto').val(previousQueries[0]);
  }
}
```

Please also note how the code in the updated JSFiddle uses the [datalist](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) to do autocompletion.

Comment: Thats great but need some modification. we need to show last query not first. I did that. here is the updated version http://jsfiddle.net/cbmag0jf/6/

I also write some code but its working for unlimited not just for 5. you can check here http://jsfiddle.net/cbmag0jf/5/

In this i am using array concept .

Comment: Yes, the approach is flexible in the order as well as the number of entries shown.